# Trying to set height of iframe to div height in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hello i'm trying to build a chrome extension. I load the css inside a content script with most of my code inside an iframe like this:

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute("id", "meineIFRAME");
iframe.style.position = "fixed";
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);

iframe.contentDocument.head.innerHTML = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + chrome.extension.getURL("divstyle.css") + "'>";

var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.setAttribute("id","testBox");
```

At the end of my code i need to set the height of the iframe to the div within it, the problem(i have discovered) is that the height of the div is given incorrectly as the css hasn't finished loading...

Iv'e spent 2 days on this now, feel iv'e given it a good try. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think Chrome doesn't fire a separate `load` event for a stylesheet element but you can try checking `iframe.contentDocument.styleSheets.length` in setInterval function.

Comment: I suggest injecting JS into the iframe that would call a parent function when ready. Basic ``child.js`` that does ``window.parent.myFunction()`` seems to work, but I'm suspecting it may also run into race conditions. So it is wise to inject JS that waits for the DOM ready of the iframe.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm. Setinterval seems do have done the trick although it feels a bit hacky.. Idc though :^) It should be stable. iframe.contentDocument.styleSheets.length reports either 1 or 0 though which i find a bit strange...

Comment: I spoke too soon. checking that iframe.contentDocument.styleSheets.length was 1 didnt work. It seems to be three values reported by chrome. First the value without the css loaded, then some other value, then 3rd (correct) value. length is sat on 2nd value. Seems i got it working with a settimeout function. I'm pretty much just banking on the css being loaded after it loads though, although it seems to work with very low values(3 ms) and i have it sat to 100 ms, so should be safe right? ( also have "security function" that launches after 1 second. Feels hackish but should be safe?

Comment: I've also used 100ms in similar case so I don't know if there's a better method...